# View port 8080 output from own computer

Tags: networking, streaming, webcam, mjpeg

I'm following the tutorial here to learn how to stream video between computers.

http://rtcl.kaist.ac.kr/~bkkim/lecture/designlab/DesignLab_RoboCam_Lab6_C.pdf

After installing the recommended libraries and compiling the source for mjpg-streamer, I'm instructed to run the script and then view the output from another computer. By default, the output is sent to port 8080. However, I'm just trying to view the output from my computer's webcam with the same computer. What web address calls my own computer?

Text from the tutorial:

> Depending on the webcam attached and its capabilities the messages
>   output to the terminal will be different. However, if it has worked
>   and is running correctly then you shouldn't be returned to your
>   prompt. Next go to the browser on your computer and enter the IP
>   address of your Beaglebone Black and specify port 8080 - you will see
>   a little web page load with your cameras video output embedded within
>   it. In my case the url will be
>
> http://192.168.0.10:8080
>
> And that's it - mjpg-streamer up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of the following *should* work:

- http://localhost:8080
- http://`<yourIPaddress>`:8080
- http://`<yourmachinename>`:8080

Obviously, replace the IP address or your machine name with the proper data

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to add that the default IP address of your own computer is 127.0.0.1, so http://127.0.0.1:8080/ is what solved it for me.

Comment: @wyverniv 127.0.0.1 is the default [loopback address](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjThaL_yN_KAhWLsxQKHd4mCkcQFggvMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webopedia.com%2FTERM%2FL%2Floopback_address.html&usg=AFQjCNG3nuBn3G_bkgRFIckE-f9gyIsbxA&sig2=XHuKRKXF2GPGdSvRHsKMRw), not your default IP address.  Localhost is set to the loopback, which is 127.0.0.1.  Still has the same result.